# BLDC motor thrust - I can't measure the same values as provided from manufacturer

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, measurement

I was trying to measure thrust of this BLDC motor - T-Motor AS 2820 880kv. I've also got official T-motor AS series test data for this particular model ([here](https://www.bighobby.cz/user/related_files/data_z_pr__behu_testovani_motoru_2820.pdf)). I've tried to measure the thrust of the motor myself with my own built testbench. But I cannot get the same values of thrust. With propeller APC 12x6 I can get 900 g of thrust (15 V, 33 A) - but with this power I should get over 2000 g of thrust. I've tried to build two versions of the testbench, but it seems to give almost the same results. I also attached photos of the two testbenches I made, maybe I'm doing something wrong... I am using power supply Kavan P40 (so no Li-po battery). My ESC is FOXY G2 R-40SB 40A. I am controlling the motor via arduino signals (basically a command esc.writeMicroseconds(val);)

Do you have an idea, why I cannot measure the same high values as provided from manufacturer?

Thank you!

Testbech version 1:
[image: Testbech version 1:]

Testbech version 2:

[image]

Comment: Did you measure the RPM to make sure it was as the data sheet? Did you consider mounting the motor significantly higher than the scales in picture 2?

Comment: Ask yourself the question - does the manufacturer have an incentive to quote a larger number, or a smaller number, than the true value of thrust? Are you using the same set of conditions as the manufacturer for measurement? Same temperature (motor and air), supply voltage, ESC quality, RPM, prop, clear air around the prop?

Comment: Thrust is the reduction in weight on the scales, right? Otherwise prop is wrong way round and much less efficient.

Comment: Wow, Tmotor sometimes simply lie on datasheets. Three years ago I had to argue and yell on their engineers until they agreed there was a problem. They never fixed it.

Comment: Regardless, do you have a chart of thrust vs speed? Power may be compromised if efficiency is poor, which is a whole different story.